# Props.email value not printed on screen in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-props, onsubmit

*See app.js and ternaryi.js I pass the email value in ternaryi and want to print on screen but only the count will be printed can anyone hep me to solve this problem.*

**App.js**

```html
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Ternaryi from "./Ternaryi";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={getFormData}>
        <select onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)}>
          <option>select option</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </form>
      <Ternaryi name={count}/>
    </div>
  );
  function getFormData(e) {
    console.log(count);
    <Ternaryi email={"hyy"}/>
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Ternary.js**

```html
import {useState} from 'react';
function Ternaryi(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>email = {props.email}</h1>
        {props.name==1? <h1>Welcome user 1</h1>:props.name==2? <h1>Welcome user 2</h1>:<h1>Welcome user 3</h1>}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default Ternaryi;
```

[react image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDAUW.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `email` attribute in the `JSX` element:

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(null);
  
  function getFormData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(count);
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <form onSubmit={getFormData}>
        <select onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)}>
          <option>select option</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>
      </form>
      <Ternaryi email='hyy' name={count} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```